# How to add a textview and a button, dynamically in a ListView in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

In my app I have a `ListView` for listing some textviews and buttons ,also have an `ImageView` on the top,i have added parallax scrollview between this,now I want to add some textviews and buttons dynamically in the `ListView` . I have this  code ;but it is not working.I am a beginner,so I could not find the actual problem. Can anybody help me out,and Please excuse my language problem?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int lastTop = 0;
    //ImageView image;
    ListView listView;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    public void parallax(final View v) {
        final Rect r = new Rect();
        v.getLocalVisibleRect(r);

        if (lastTop != r.top) {
            lastTop = r.top;
            v.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    v.setY((float) (r.top / 2.0));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        //Dynamic textvieww
        final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //Create four
        for(int j=0;j<=4;j++)
        {
            // Create LinearLayout
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            // Create TextView
            TextView product = new TextView(this);
            product.setText(" Product"+j+"    ");
            ll.addView(product);

            // Create TextView
            TextView price = new TextView(this);
            price.setText("  $"+j+"     ");
            ll.addView(price);

            // Create Button
            final Button btn = new Button(this);
            // Give button an ID
            btn.setId(j+1);
            btn.setText("Add To Cart");
            // set the layoutParams on the button
            btn.setLayoutParams(params);

            final int index = j;
            // Set click listener for button
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.i("TAG", "index :" + index);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Clicked Button Index :" + index,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            //Add button to LinearLayout
            ll.addView(btn);
            //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
            lm.addView(ll);
        }
        //EOF Dynamic
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
        //Image view block
        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
        this.imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        Button photoButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        //imageview block end
        // image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        listView.addHeaderView(view);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                parallax(imageView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                parallax(imageView);
            }
        });
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

     }
  }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="in.zoid.parallaxtutorial.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" ></ImageView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Load Picture"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take Picture"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put a view inside of your listitem and dynamically create button and textView and add to that view

Answer (score 0):

[See this Example it may useful to add data dynamically in list view in android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-items-to-listview-in-android/)

Comment: @Hari Haran: Any solution for my problem?